# How to Wrap a TextBlock in a Horizontal StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock, stackpanel

I have a series of TextBlocks that all need to have their text wrapped, but when placed in a Horizontal StackPanel none of the TextBlock's text is wrapped. Originally I just had a StackPanel of several TextBlocks which worked fine, but I added a bullet to each TextBlock for easier reading, and therefore with my new implementation I lost the wrapping ability

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="•"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="InstructionsTextBlock1" Margin="12,0,12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.InstructionsPage_InstructionsTextBlock1, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
```

How might I wrap the text in the second TextBlock within the Horizontal StackPanel?

Comment: You can also get the problem solved if you assign a width figure to your stack panel. It takes auto here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the StackPanel implementation all together, and creating a grid whereby I had 2 Columns and enough Rows for each bullet/textblock combination. I then set the first column to a small width, and the other column to the remaining width. I then added each bullet/textblock combination accordingly.

```
<ScrollViewer>
                <Grid Margin="12,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".025*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="•"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="InstructionsTextBlock1" Margin="12,0,12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.InstructionsPage_InstructionsTextBlock1, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                    </TextBlock>

                ...
              </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer
```